# Finder hiding items under a grey box in list view

Tags: macos, finder, mojave

In Mojave, when I open a finder window, I don't see all the requested columns displayed.

For example, the finder should open for the desktop and look like this:

[image: Normal view]

However, I see this:

[image]

Which looks like a window within the finder window is not wide enough to display my columns.

So, I resize the window and columns.
I delete all the .DS_Store files on my Mac.
I save the new finder window setting as the default.
Then when I open a new finder window, I have the same problem.

How do I remove this overlay ?

Answer (score 2):

Go in Finder to View and select "Hide Preview"

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was just the preview pane which I had forgotten about.

I wasn't expecting this to be available in list mode; so I wasn't expecting it to cover anything there.